# Angularjs spinner on dataload from server

Tags: angularjs, spinner

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="spinner-modal" ng-show="spinning">
            <div class="spinner">
                <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-5x fa-spin"></i>
            </div>
</div>
```

---

This is my controller

```
controllers.controller('CenterCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$sce', 'recommendationService','SpinnerModule', 
        function ($scope, $sce, $rootScope, recommendationService,SpinnerModule) {
        $scope.getRecommendation = function() {
            $scope.spinning = true;
            $scope.$broadcast("spinner:start", {username: $scope.user.username });
            $scope.$broadcast("myEvent", {username: $scope.user.username });
            recommendationService.getNext().then(function(response) {
                console.log(response.data);
                $scope.recommendation = $sce.trustAsHtml(response.data);
                console.log($scope.recommendation);
            });
        };

        $scope.getRecommendation();
```

Data from recommendations shows up fine without a spinner. When i add this spinner

i get an error saying
"Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: SpinnerModuleProvider <- SpinnerModule"
I'm new to this please help me out. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-busy

Answer (score 1):

you have the order of the dependencies wrong

```
['$scope', '$rootScope', '$sce', 'recommendationService','SpinnerModule', 
        function ($scope, $sce, $rootScope, recommendationService,SpinnerModule)
```

**$sce** and **$rootscope** are not defined in the same order from the annotation to your controller, that's required for angular to inject the correct dependency into your controller.

Comment: is the spinner a service, factory, is a library or you created it?